# How can I iterate over items from two different lists in Clojure in lockstep?

Tags: clojure

I have two lists in clojure a and b that have the same length. I want to do the following

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
        do_something(a[i], b[i])
```

What I have tried but hasn't worked. `for` doesn't iterate over corresponding elements but all possible combinations:

```
(for [i a j b] (do-something i j))
```

Comment: ...that said, Clojure's `for` isn't equivalent to Python's `for` either (it's lazy, and doesn't force evaluation); I wonder if you want `doseq`.

Comment: That said -- what types are your Clojure arguments? If they're vectors, a direct translation of the Python code will work (for regular `seq`s, getting the length up-front can be an expensive operation).

Comment: Hmm. Really, you could just `(doall (map do-something a b))` and not need the loop at all.

Comment: doall proved to be much more efficient.

Comment: Hmm. It's going to be a little more efficient because it's not creating transient vectors that just get garbage collected, but if it's *much* more efficient, I'm curious as to whether we've got something else going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idiomatic equivalent might be:

```
(doall (map do-something a b))
```

...or, as an expanded version of that that still has you writing your own loop:

```
(doseq [[i j] (map vector a b)]
  (do-something i j))
```

- Because `for` is lazy, it may not actually evaluate your whole sequence unless something is consuming its result; `doseq` always calls `do-something` on everything.
- `map somefunc arg1 arg2` calls `somefunc` with each set of values in `arg1` and `arg2`, exactly what you're looking for here.

---

A more direct translation might look like:

```
(doseq [i (range (count a))]
  (do-something (nth a i) (nth b i)))
```

...but don't use that; both `count` and `nth` can be slow or unavailable, depending on the specific collection types in use.

Answer (score 1):

Add the "if" condition in the loop:

```clj
(doseq [[x y] (map vector a b)
        :when (= x y)]
 (do_something x y))
```

Comment: Heh -- I quite missed that part of the question. That said, if the values are equal, why pass two different arguments at all? This smells like something where the logic was written assuming mutable values.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a convenience function, [I already have one](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.core.html#var-map-let) that does this:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t]))

  (let [xs [ 1  2  3]
        ys [10 20 30]]
    (is= [11 22 33]
      (t/map-let [x xs
                  y ys]
        (+ x y))))
```

So you write the bindings to `x` and `y` like a `let` form, but then it operates on the local "variables" as if in a `mapv`.